# SQL - Select row only if column is equal with the current time

Tags: php, sql, datetime

I have a PHP script that should display the value from column A only if the datetime from column B is equal with the current time.

```
Column A | Column B
------------------------------
House    | 2013-06-28 12:47:30
Dog      | 2013-06-28 12:47:52
Forrest  | 2013-06-30 14:54:12
```

In our case, if the current time is 2013-06-28 12:47:44, then the script should display House and Dog.

The idea is that I should get the row only if Column B it is the same with the current year-month-day hour-minute, and not seconds.

I tried DATE_SUB(CURTIME()-59) but it's not working... How can I do it only with SQL?

Comment: What is the type of column_b? Varchar or datetime ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(column_b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = STR_TO_DATE(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

Comment: Thank you Yogesh, your SQL is the perfect choise. Only one notice: It should be "%H" not "%h" for hour.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(column_b, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = DATE_FORMAT(now(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

- Read more about `DATE_FORMAT()` [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Comment: Did you see @Yogesh's answer ?

Comment: Did you see that I use a different function?

Comment: I see that you made the same mistake using `%h` instead of `%H`